# Differentiate between posts and pages in search results

Tags: posts, loop, search, pages

How can one differentiate between posts and pages in search results?

What I need to do is show a `the_time` div for posts but not show it for pages, as it's irrelevant.

With a function? `<?php if (!is_page()) }` in the loop below doesn't help.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

//prevent this div from displaying for pages: 
<div class="searchdate"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>

<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?><?php else : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php //prevent this div from displaying for pages:
if ( get_post_type() != 'page' ) : ?>
   <div class="searchdate"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The `is_page()` conditional tag only checks if currently displayed content is a single page view. Nothing for you at this point. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: Didn't know the difference in the conditional tags. That works great. Thanks.